# Save image and retrieve it to velocity template

Tags: image, spring, velocity

I'm using spring 2.5 + velocity for my application. I have requirement to upload an image and retrieve it.

I need to just save the url in the DB ,but not the actual image.

how to achieve this requirement, so that it will work in production environment as well.

I did in the following way, but i'm unable to retrieve the image.

I uploaded the image and save it to a local folder in local disk.(D:/..)
in velocity template i ponited the img src to the picture location(i.e: D:/..)
And, i'm able to see the picture using firebug, but picture is not displayed the browser.

Please help me in finding the efficient way to implement this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: to put it simply, how store the images as a file in the file system and create a record in a table with the exact path to that image. and how to display that back in the ui. I did this by storing the images in "D:/home", but while retrieveing img tag not detecting the url from local disk

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your pictures are located in the same folder which is web accessible (you can access it via `http://`, like `http://example.com/images/`), you should only save image filename into the database, like `image.jpg`.

After that you can build image url for display by appending image folder url (usually stored in config file) and filename from db.

So at the end it would be something like:

```
<img src="${imgRootUrl}${filename}">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Your answer relates when the application is in production environmet. But when working in local machine how could i achieve that? As i mentioned i'm able to save the image in localDisk D:/home location. but unable retreive the image from the same location(<img src="file:///D:/home/abc.jpg"), but when i debug using firebug i'm able to see the image for that URL.

Comment: @Shekar When developing usually you need to have a web server running on localhost so you can see the website. If you don't have one then you probably should install it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a web server. I started the server and run the application. I uploaded the image to the local disk. while retrieving, I'm facing this problem. So, are ypu suggesting to save the image to webserver? but when i restart i'll lose previously saved images..right?

Comment: @Shekar Webserver is linked to some root directory. Lets say it is `d:/www/`. This means that if you go to `http://localhost/page.html` webserver would serve you `d:/www/page.html`. With your images you just need to put them under webserver root folder, for example into `d:/www/images/`, so you can access them through `http://localhost/images/`.